# Why setState() isn't working in React in my case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm trying to implement a shopping cart by using contexts. The context works fine, but I need to create a method that removes one product each click. To do that I have to use `useState()` function. However, it doesn't even change the data in the state.

**Here is my code for the function. Let me know if something isn't clear**

**For more info. `productsToPurchase` is an array that have all the purchased products which looks like that:**

`[{itemId: "ps-5", qty:2},{itemId: "iphone-xr", qty:4},{itemId:"ps-4", qty:7}]`

```
export const CartContext = createContext()

class CartContextProvider extends Component {

    state = {
        productsToPurchase: [],
        totalPrice:[]
    }

    addProduct = (itemId, prices) => {
        this.setState(oldState => {
            const objWithIdExist = oldState.productsToPurchase.find((o) => o.itemId === itemId);
            return {
                productsToPurchase: !objWithIdExist
                    ? [...oldState.productsToPurchase, { itemId, qty: 1, price: prices }]
                    : oldState.productsToPurchase.map((o) =>
                        o.itemId !== itemId ? o : { ...o, qty: o.qty + 1 }
                    )
            }
        })

        this.setState(oldState=>{
            return{
                totalPrice: getTotalAmount(oldState.productsToPurchase)
            }
        })
    }

    decreaseProduct = (itemId) =>{

        this.setState(oldState=>{

            // catch the item by mapping
            return oldState.productsToPurchase.map(product=>{
                if (product.itemId === itemId){
                    if (product.qty === 1){
                        //remove the product from the list
                        console.log("qty is 1!")
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Quantity is more than 1")
                        return  {...product, qty: product.qty - 1}
                    }
                }
            })

        })

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <CartContext.Provider value={{...this.state, addProduct: this.addProduct, decreaseProduct: this.decreaseProduct}}>
                {this.props.children}
            </CartContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}

function getTotalAmount(productsToPurchase) {

    const totalPrice = []

    productsToPurchase.map((product, productIndex) =>{
        product.price.map((price, priceIndex)=>{
            if (productIndex === 0){
                totalPrice.push({currency: price.currency, amount: price.amount * product.qty})
            }
            else {
                totalPrice.map(total=>{
                    if (total.currency === price.currency){
                        total.amount = total.amount + (price.amount * product.qty)
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    })

    return totalPrice
}

export default CartContextProvider;
```

Comment: You need to return the new state in your `setState()` callback. See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: @Phil how's that?

Comment: Your callback (`oldState => { ... }`) doesn't return anything so the new state is never written

Comment: @Phil But there is a return in `else`

Comment: That's the return in the `map` callback, not the `setState` callback. You also seem to be using `map` in place of `for..of` or `forEach` which isn't what it's for (why do devs keep doing this?)

Comment: @asemshaat you're not returning the new state. It should be `return oldState.productsToPurchase.map(...`. The function you pass into `setState` needs to return the new state. The return you're talking about is the one nested _inside_ the map function. Also, if you want to remove products from the list you'll need to use `.filter` too, or alternatively `.reduce` can be used to essentially map and filter in one iteration

Comment: @Jayce444 I added  `return oldState.productsToPurchase.map(...`, but when I click on the button it actually adds a new object to `productsToPurchase` array

Comment: @Jayce444 I hope you got my point

Comment: It seems odd that the provider is a class component and everything else is hooks and functional components. I'd make everything functional.

Comment: @TrueWill I don't want to change the whole component to functional. All I need to do is to make the required change in `return  {...product, qty: product.qty - 1}` which is in `decreaseProduct()` function. `addProduct()` is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to subtract 1 from the selected product quantity and remove it if it hits 0, try this

```js
// Make sure you return the new state object in its entirety
this.setState(({ productsToPurchase, ...oldState }) => ({
  ...oldState,
  productsToPurchase: productsToPurchase.reduce((arr, product) => {
    // is this the selected product?
    if (product.itemId === itemId) {
      // product qty > 1, include it with decrement
      if (product.qty > 1) {
        return [...arr, {
          ...product,
          qty: product.qty - 1
        }]
      }
      return arr // otherwise exclude this product
    }
    // otherwise, just include this product
    return [...arr, product]
  }, [])
}))
```

Comment: That seems too many lines of codes. In my case I just found that I have to add `return` before `oldState.productsToPurchase.map(product=>{`. What should I do at  `return{
                        productsToPurchase: { ...product, qty: product.qty - 1 }
                    }
`

Comment: I'm really not sure what you mean. FYI, without the comments and spacing, it's 12 lines compared to your original 13 which doesn't even remove the product from the array

Comment: I haven't worked on removing the product yet when `qty = 0`. I'm now working on removing the product when `qty>0` which is in the `else` part

Comment: It's in line number 15. If you count from the first line

Comment: @asemshaat I've changed to a _reduce_ instead which uses fewer lines. IMO it's not as readable but that's subjective

Comment: Btw, my method is in a class component not a function so I can't use `useState()`

Comment: @asemshaat your question literally says _"I have to use `useState()` function"_

Comment: check my edit. I just uploaded the whole code for my context file, which is a class component

Comment: Your question still says the same about `useState()`. In any case, I've removed that advice from my answer. Does the code above solve your problem? If not, what's it doing wrong?

Comment: I still don't why I need to use `useState()` while `addProduct()` works fine. Take a look at it please.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. I've removed all references to `useState()` from my answer even though [**your question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69997048/283366) still mentions it for some reason. **Does the code in this answer solve your problem?**

Comment: It worked with me. But I was wondering If I could make a small change in my code rather than implementing new code. Cuz I believe that my issue could be just a missing word or character. I hope you got my point.